# Best place for Bengin files for training a classifier?

Tags: dataset

Trying to train a Deep neural network classifier, and I got a big data set from virusshare.com, however I also need some normal (non-malware) files. Format must be a PE (x64 or x86).

Does anyone know where to get such a dataset? Or would I have to create my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [VirusTotal](https://virustotal.com). VirusTotal got a [Private API](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/private-api/) where you can query files (for example only those that has 0 positives) and then download the files, you need to contact them to understand how much it cost.

If you don't need the binary itself and you are using different information from the files structure you can use [endgame's dataset](https://github.com/endgameinc/ember)